how to insert from __future__ import annotations in a future proof way
The Python 3.14 documentation states that the
from __future__ import annotations

directive will be considered deprecated with the release of 3.14 and expected to be removed at some future date.
It is going to be a while (not before 2029), but I would like to know if it is possible to write Python files that are future proof.
I cannot do something like:
import sys
if (3, 7) <= sys.version_info() < (3, 14):
    from __future__ import annotations

as from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of a file.
As I have had the need to support some of my libraries, well beyond the end-of-life date of specific Python versions, I foresee that this is going to be a problem. I can probably strip these directives during the build process, but this would force me to create non-universal wheels, complicating the build process.
Is there a simple way to insert/use this directive, in Python files, in a way that is future proof?

What stops you from including from __future__ import annotations at the start of every file and then, when it becomes deprecated, it should not break the scripts (just become irrelevant) and if there is a warning for the deprecation then you can either ignore or suppress it (since that line is probably still going to be necessary for backwards compatibility on earlier versions).

@MTO I know how to deal with deprecations, that is easy, and not what this question is about. It will break the scripts when this directive gets removed (in Python 3.19 or so), which will then be only compatible with non-EOL Python versions, and that is not good enough in my experience.

How do you expect this question to be answered when we do not know how the Python team will handle the removal of the from __future__ import annotations feature (in, as you say, Python 3.19 or so)? The simple answer would be use the import now and assume that, in the future, they aren't going to do something that breaks all the code using it (and it will be gracefully deprecated and removed). If the Python team do decide it will be a breaking change then deal with it when you know for sure (i.e. at that point run a find-replace to remove it from the files).

I never asked "how is the python team going to handle this"?. I asked if there is a way around what is going to happen to code that include the directive in the simplistic way (that I am not aware of). Not when it is just deprecated, that is uninteresting but as it is going to be removed. What is clear (if you read the 3.14 documentation) is that is going to be removed as announced. That is different from e.g. the Python2 directive from __future__ import print_function, that one is not removed, and you can still use it in Python 3.14 (at least in the alpha releases).

CPython issue: 3.14's "What's new" says __future__.annotations will be removed, but it must not.

Thanks for posting this, I had the exact same question. I don't quite understand how can PEP 563 and PEP 649 both be Status: Accepted - these approaches seem fundamentally incompatible.

It seems like PEP 563 is dying or dead - https://github.com/python/peps/pull/3701

Apparently it will be a breaking change sometime in the future. PEP 749 elaborates:

Rejected alternatives
Immediately make the future import a no-op: We considered applying PEP 649 semantics to all code in Python 3.14, making the future import
a no-op. However, this would break code that works in 3.13 under the
following set of conditions:

__future__ import annotations is active
There are annotations that rely on forward references
Annotations are eagerly evaluated at import time, for example by a metaclass or class or function decorator. For example, this currently
applies to the released version of typing_extensions.TypedDict.

This is expected to be a common pattern, so we cannot afford to break
such code during the upgrade from 3.13 to 3.14.
Such code would still break when the future import is eventually
removed. However, this is many years in the future, giving affected
decorators plenty of time to update their code.


Make the future import a no-op in the future: Instead of eventually making from __future__ import annotations a SyntaxError, we could
make it do nothing instead at some point after Python 3.13 reaches its
end-of-life. This still has some of the same issues outlined above
around making it a no-op now, although the ecosystem would have had
much longer to adapt. It is better to have users explicitly remove the
future import from their code in the future once they have confirmed
they do not rely on stringized annotations.

It appears the behaviour of stringized annotations will change and will require you to update your code, as far as I understand the PEP. If you do rely on evaluating stringized annotations, you'll need to transition to using a new annotationlib.
So, for now, it appears the answer is to use the import, but be prepared to check all your code again during the transition phase, which will be years in the making, and actually remove it eventually. But who knows, plans might still change if there is too much pushback to such a huge breaking change.

The answer should mention that PEP 749 is still Status: Draft. There is no precedent for breaking a future statement before. Even the "joke" one (from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL) is being fixed when it regressed in Python 3.13.
